# How to read the identity of a record inserted into database table with Pervasive SQL?

Tags: c#, pervasive

I am developing a C# Windows Form app and need to insert a record into a table and then read back the identity of the record and pass that identity to another part of the program. See code below.

The ID_COLUMN is of PSQL Type Identity. Also Note:

Pervasive SQL does not support the SCOPE_IDENTITY. From the documentation, @@identity returns the value of the most recently inserted Identity column. If the table does not have an identity column, @@identity will return null. If you have two inserts, the @@identity returns the last value inserted.

Other Notes:  Pervasive version is v11 and Using data provider provided with Pervasive.

```
using Pervasive.Data.SqlClient;

int newIdentity = 0;
string connectionString = 
  "Server Name=myServerAddress;Database Name=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;"
PsqlConnection connection = new PsqlConnection(connectionString); 
string insertStatment= 
  "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 ( ID_COLUMN, DATA_COLUMN_1, DATA_COLUMN_2 ) " + 
  "        VALUES ( 0, 'My First Name', 'My Last Name' )";
try{
   PsqlCommand insertCommand = new PsqlCommand(insertStatment,connection);
   connection.Open();
   int rowCount = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if ( rowCount > 0 )
      {
         string selectIdentityStatment =
            " SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM TABLE_1 ";
         PsqlCommand selectIdentity =
         new PsqlCommand(selectIdentityStatment, connection );
         newIdentity =
           (int)selectIdentity.ExecuteScalar();  // THIS IS RETURNING NULL
       }
       else
        { // nothing was inserted
          // newIdentity = 0
        }
      }
Finally {
         Connection.Close();
        }
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I ran your code against my v11.30 PSQL server and it returned the correct value for the Identity.  What exact version of PSQL are you using?  What's the version of the Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.DLL you are using?

Comment: Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.DLL Runtime Version v2.0.50727, Version 4.  I am using .NET frame work 4.0

Comment: Also -  this code works on our test database.  When we connect to our live data is when the problems start.  Sometime this will succeed, but most of the time it fails ( as of lately ).  I wounder if there is another user or process stepping in and creating a record, causing the @@Identity Global to be set to null before I can read it back.  Is that even possible?  And how would you get around the possibility?

Comment: Further trouble shooting of this problem revealed that there was a problem with the database engine.  Rebooting the database server seemed to fix the issue I was having.  See this link for further details: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1777356

Answer (score -1):

New version of Actian PSQL Ado.net providers are available with PSQL V12 and V13. Please let us know if there are any issues with the current versions.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because IMHO it would have been more appropriate to simply comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the ado.net providers.  I get the same results if I run the query from the Pervasive Command Center and got the same behavior.